# How to show products to user based on user's search and products user clicked?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to know how to show user those products that are related to the user's search and products user clicked... Like in alibaba all the products on the homepage are based on user's activity( user's search and products user clicked). I mean how can i do this in flutter and firebase...

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a query? If so, then the answer is yes, you can do that in Firebase/Flutter and is pretty well coved in the Getting Started Guide and the documentation [How to Query](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#document--query-snapshots). Is there something more?

Comment: no this is not what i mean

Comment: In my app's home page i want to show all relative products that user searched or clicked...

Comment: If you want to show all products that the user is searching for, in programming, that's called a query. For example, suppose a user searched for (queried) red and blue shirts. Your code would be a query of `let foundShirts = allShirts where shirt.color = red OR shirt.color = blue`  <-Just pseudo code. If that's not what you're asking, please update THE QUESTION and make it clear so we can try to help.

Comment: yeah that is what i mean. but to do it dynamically. for example if i want to search array of a list like ［red, blue,green,grey,black,blue,orange］how can i do it

Comment: like search that above color's array in all products.

Comment: I mean I can use loop. but isn't there any other way to do this??

Comment: There are several ways to do that but again, it's all covered in the documentation for both FlutterFire and in the Firestore docs. Its pretty well covered with example code as well. take a look